# Is the operadic butterfly symmetric?

Tags: operads, symmetry, koszul-duality

The operadic butterfly is a diagram in the category of operads in vector spaces. It extends the short exact sequence relating commutative, associative and Lie operads.

$$\begin{array}{ccccc}
  & Dend & & & & Dias & \newline
 \nearrow & &\searrow & &\nearrow & &\searrow\newline
Zinb &  &  &Ass & & & \quad Leib \newline
 \searrow & &\nearrow & &\searrow & &\nearrow\newline
  & Comm & & & & Lie & \newline 
\end{array}$$

Here is a [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0409183) by Loday in which some discussion can be found. As the reference explains, the Koszul duality functor, $\mathcal{O}\mapsto \mathcal{O}^!$, gives the above diagram symmetry about the vertical axis.

Is the butterfly also symmetric about the horizontal axis?

In other words, does there exist a functor $F : Operad(C) \to Operad(C)$, where $C$ is vector spaces or chain complexes, such that $F\circ F \simeq 1$, $F$ fixes the operads: $Zinb$, $Ass$ and $Leib$, and exchanges the pairs: $(Dend,Dias) \leftrightarrow (Comm,Lie)$.

Comment: Shouldn't such a functor also interchange Zinb and Leib?

Comment: Do you also want your horizontal symmetry to extend to the big diagram on page 3 of http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0409183v1.pdf?

Comment: Dan: An example which does that would be interesting too.

André: It is reasonable to ask that $F$ swaps $\chi$ and $Vect$. 

Comment: It looks difficult for any kind of reasonable construction to exchange  $\chi$ and $Vect$: The operad $Vect$ is completely trivial (zero generators), while $\chi$ is a mess (actually, there are two versions of it -- which one do you want??). If you think that $\chi$ can come out of $Vect$ by some kind of natural construction, then you are also implicitly saying that $\chi$ is a very important operad and that everybody should know about it: are you claiming that?

Comment: The larger diagram does suggest investigating funny extensions. An $F$ defined using $\chi$ wouldn't increase its importance (any more than Loday's paper). If such a construction exists then probably $Operad(C)$ has lots of messy symmetries. It just seemed like an interesting question.

Comment: In the same spirit, one can ask about an involutive functor $G : Operad(C) \to Operad(C)$ that fixes $Zin$, $Ass$, and $Lieb$, sends $Dend$ to $Lie$, and $Comm$ to $Dias$ (and fixes $\mathcal{X}^\pm$ and $Vect$).


Comment: Unfortunately, these results: http://arxiv.org/abs/1312.4994 do not apply to dg operads. May be some modification could be used to show the uniqueness of dg duality in this setting and it would follow that the operadic butterfly isn't so symmetric.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have never seen such a functor and I doubt that it would exist. For instance, the operad Com is symmetric and one-dimensional in every arity. Whereas the operad Dend is regular (coming from a non-symmetric one) and is generated by two (non-symmetric) generators. I also now no non-trivial functor which preserves Zinb or Leib.

Can I ask why you are looking for such a functor (despite the symmetric shape of the operadic butterfly)?